# Задача про листок и письмо

Tags: c++, математика

Условие задачи:

> Валя устала от социальных сетей и решила написать своей подруге Саше письмо на прямоугольном листе бумаге. Длины сторон листа равны n и m сантиметрам. Потом она нашла конверт
> прямоугольной формы, длины сторон которого равны h и w сантиметрам.
> К сожалению, письмо может не помещаться в конверт, в этом случае Вале придется несколько
> раз сложить письмо. За одно действие Валя может сложить письмо пополам по вертикали или по
> горизонтали.
> После того, как Валя, при необходимости, несколько раз сложит письмо пополам, она планирует
> положить его в конверт. Валя — очень аккуратная девочка, она всегда кладёт письмо в конверт
> таким образом, чтобы его стороны были параллельны сторонам конверта. Письмо помещается в
> конверт, если длины его стороны не больше длин соответствующих сторон конверта. Прежде чем
> положить письмо в конверт, Валя может повернуть его на 90 градусов. Например, если длины сторон
> письма равны 10 и 20 сантиметрам, а длины сторон конверта равны 20 и 10 сантиметрам, Вале не
> нужно сгибать письмо, она может повернуть его на 90 градусов и положить в конверт.
> Валя не хочет, чтобы письмо получилось очень мятым, поэтому она хочет сложить письмо пополам минимальное число раз. Помогите ей выяснить, какое минимальное число раз ей придется
> сложить письмо перед тем, как она сможет положить его в конверт.

Идеи как написать решение минимальны, вот что получилось, но программа работает не правильно, думаю что настолько в лоб решать задачу плохо, но других идей я не нашел.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    int h, w;
    int answ = 0;
    cin >> n >> m; // лист
    cin >> h >> w; // конверт

    if (n != h && m != w || n != w && m != h)
    {
        while (n >= h)
        {
            while (n >= w)
            {
                n / 2;
                answ++;
            }

        }
        while (m >= h)
        {
            while (m >= w)
            {
                w / 2;
                answ++;
            }
        }
        cout << answ;
    }
    else
    {
        answ = 0;
        cout << answ;
    }
    cout << answ;


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Идея решения:

Мы проверяем обе стороны листа с сторонами конверта, если стороны листа не равняются сторонам конверта, то мы делим стороны напополам и проверяем еще раз, при этом накапливает `answ` как ответ, не знаю насколько это верно, но только это лезет в голову

UPD:

Я понял что мое решение имеет право на жизнь, но в консоли не выводится answ, помогите пожалуйста

```
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    int h, w;
    int answ = 0;
    cin >> n >> m; // лист
    cin >> h >> w; // конверт

    if (n != h & m != w || n != w & m != h)
    {
        while (n >= h || n >= w)
        {

            n /= 2;
            answ += 1;
        }

            while (m >= h || m >= w)
            {
                
                    w /= 2;
                    answ += 1;
                
            }
            cout << answ << endl;
        
        
    }
    else
    {
        cout << answ << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Дайте-ка URL задачи...

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/school/archive/2018-2019/ru-olymp-team-spb-2018-problems.pdf

Comment: Я имел в виду — проверяющей системы.

Comment: Проверяющий - преподаватель

Comment: `while (w >= w)` ??? `w / 2;` ???

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пояснение вашего способа решения. Что вы хотели сделать? Что не получилось?

Comment: Действительно глупая опечатка, исправил на `m`, сейчас изменю вопрос немного

Comment: `w /= 2;` ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте попробуем подкинуть идею.

Если сложить листок `a` раз по горизонтали, и `b` раз по вертикали, то размеры станут

```
m/2^a, n/2^b
```

А по отношению `m/w` и `n/h` нетрудно найти `a` и `b`

С другой стороны, если смотреть отношения `n/w` и `m/h` (другая ориентация), то получатся другие числа `a'`и `b'`.

Остаётся только проверить, какая сумма меньше `a+b` или `a'+b'`

```
int steps(unsigned long long v) {
    int k = 0;
    unsigned long long t = 1;
    while (t < v) {
        k++;
        t *= 2;
    }
    return k;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long h, w, lh, lw;
    unsigned long long answ = 0;
    cin >> lh >> lw; // лист
    cin >> h >> w; // конверт

    int a1 = steps((lh + h - 1) / h); //округляем вверх
    int b1 = steps((lw + w - 1) / w);
    int a2 = steps((lh + w - 1) / w);
    int b2 = steps((lw + h - 1) / h);

    cout << min(a1 + b1, a2 + b2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, помогите пожалуйста просто вывести ответ в консоль, потому что я уже не знаю что не так

Comment: Это вы и сами можете отдебажить. Что делается в ифе?